# Linux network programming. "read([...])" whats going on behind the scenes?

Tags: c, linux, network-programming

What does `ssize_t read(int fd, void * data, size_t count);` **exactly** do?

In a lot of articles in the web is often written, that it *tries* to read from or the descriptor fd. What does that mean? "It tries" :/ And how is such a socket designed? Does the OS buffer the messages coming in? Or is a read a time critical operation? I mean is there the posibility that some packages get lost, if i dont "read" in time?

*EDIT:*

I wondered a while now why this is not blocking. Then I wondered why read(...) has other parameters than all functions I saw in code snippets. Finally I realized that it is **read**(...) not **recv**(...). Unlucky that it still worked nearly as i expected. And fnuny how our ascostaivie tohuhgts paly geams wtih us. (Don't edit) I have to admit that the example german has more effect on the reader...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linux will buffer any data which arrives on a connected TCP socket, up to a few megabytes by default. You dont have to read at the exact same time the data arrives.

`netstat -tn` will show `Recv-Q` and `Send-Q` for each connected socket, which is the number of bytes queued in each direction.

Answer (score -1):

As Erik Ekman answered, the system will buffer some amount of data even if you don't read it dilligently.

After the buffer gets more and more filled, the receiver's TCP/IP implementation will reduce the advertised receive window size, causing the peer to send smaller chunks of data, effectively throttling the transfer. When the buffer is full, the window size drops to zero and the peer is allowed to send no additional data. Even if this happens, no data will be lost because the peer will resume sending the packets once the receive buffer is cleared.

A correct TCP/IP implementation guarantees that no data is just *lost* by skipping—a connection is either reliable and working or it is entirely lost, which is indicated by `read` returning -1.

Comment: Entire 2nd paragraph is incorrect. Once the receive buffer fills, the receiver advertises a zero receive window, and the sender will stop sending altogether until the receiver advertises a non-zero window. There is no slowdown and no resending, and therefore no dropping either.

Comment: @EJP The receive window will reach 0 size only when the buffer is completely full; as the buffer is getting full, the receiver will decrease it, [causing a slowdown of throughput](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_tuning#Window_size). Regardless of this, if some packets do arrive, for whatever reason, at the point when the buffer is full, they *will* be dropped.

Comment: OF course a smaller receive window causes a slowdown of throughput, but the ultimate cause of that is that the reader is slower than the writer. The reader doesn't 'instruct the peer to slow down', it instructs him how much data he is allowed to send before the window closes. If some packets do get sent into a zero receive window for whatever reason, the sender shouldn't be connected to the Internet, as it is in violation of the RFCs

Comment: @EJP Yes, the reader being slower than the writer is what happens first. "Instruct the peer to slow down" is a high-level description of what happens next as the buffer is getting full, and what you are the details of that mechanism. I will reword the answer to make it more precise.